# Javascript fullscreen request is being rejected in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web, html5-canvas, fullscreen

I am trying to make a html5 canvas fullscreen, so I used the javascript api and a button to go fullscreen.

Here is the html button code:

```
<button onclick="fullscreen()">Pantalla completa</button>
```

The fullscreen function looks like this:

```
function fullscreen(){
    var elem = myGameArea.canvas;

    try {
        if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
            prom = elem.requestFullscreen();
        } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) { /* Firefox */
        elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
        } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Chrome, Safari and Opera */
            elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
        } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE/Edge */
            elem.msRequestFullscreen();
        }         
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

This works fine with mozilla firefox, but in chrome it gives the error:
 [Browser console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkQvY.png)

I can't understand why, because I'm calling it when the user interacts, pressing the button.

Comment: Can you post your code, html and css and javascript, or a live version if you can

Comment: I'm making a simple pong game on a server. this is the url. [link]http://pong.server.tl/[link]. The button in cuestion is the "Pantalla completa" one.

Interestingly, I discovered that if I run the app in localhost it works, but when uploaded to the server doesn't. 
Maybe it has something to do with the fact that Chrome marks my page as insecure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you didn't say that you are using `iframe` element, so you need to add `allow="fullscreen"` attribute in order to do that

Comment: This is right. Unfortunatelly, as I used a free subdomain service, wich embeds my page, hosted on my homemade server, into an iframe, I can't access it.

Comment: Ok, I found a workaround for this. I just serve an html that redirects towards my server, wich now displays the page without the iframe. Thank you for your answer!